# Passing reactive data as choices for updateSelectizeInput

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I am trying to pass reactive data to **updateSelectizeInput** but instead get the following error :

**Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)**

My code is as follows :

**ui.R**

```
 library(shiny)


  ui_panel <- 
  tabPanel("Text Input Test",
          sidebarLayout(
           sidebarPanel( 


           selectizeInput('Organisations', label = "Organisation Search", 
   choices = NULL, options = list(
             placeholder = 'Type the organisation name', maxOptions = 10, 
   maxItems = 1, searchConjunction = 'and')),
           tags$style(type="text/css",
                      ".selectize-input::after{visibility:hidden;};"
                      ),


           br(),
           selectInput(
             inputId="selectData",
             label=" ",
             choices=c("Universities", "Hospitals")
           ),

           br()
         ),
         mainPanel(
           tabsetPanel(

             tabPanel("output of Organisation search 
 details",htmlOutput("orgsearchdetails"))

           )
         )
       ))


ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage(" ",ui_panel))
```

**server.R**

```
   library(shiny)


  shinyServer(
   function(input, output, session) {



    orgdata <- reactive({if(input$selectData=='Universities'){
    orgdata <- read.csv("universities.csv")
   }else if (input$selectData=='Hospitals'){ 
    orgdata <- read.csv("hospitals.csv")
    }
    orgdata
   })




    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'Organisations', choices = 
   as.character(unique(
     orgdata()$name)), server = TRUE)




  output$orgsearchdetails <-renderUI({ 


    })


  session$onSessionEnded(function() { dbDisconnect(con) })
  })
```

Is there a way I can pass the reactivity of the selectInput to the updateSelectizeInput ?

I am opting for updateSelectizeInput instead of a reactive selectInput so as to avoid populating the filed at the launch of the application.

Any help or insight is highly welcome. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not much of a shiny expert, but from the dashboards I've been building, here is what I would do. I would create a `reactiveValues` variable called `selectedData`. Then in my `observeEvent`, I would pull the csv and update the `selectedData`. The reason why I chose to use `reactiveValues` in my app is that they can be stateful rather than just always reacting to some input, and I can call them in other areas of the app that requires the same information. As for using `observeEvent`, it's simple because you can then wrap your `updateSelectizeInput` within the observer.

```
shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session) {
    # init reactiveValues
    selectedData <- reactiveValues()

    observeEvent(input$selectData, {
      if (input$selectData == "Universities") {
        selectedData$orgdata <- read.csv("universities.csv")
      } else if (input$selectData == "Hospitals") {
        selectedData$orgdata <- read.csv("hospitals.csv")
      }

      updateSelectizeInput(session, "Organisations",
                           choices = as.character(unique(selectedData$orgdata$name)),
                           server = TRUE)
    })

    ... # rest of your code

  }
)
```